# Background drawable not applying to Android button

Tags: android

I want to applying drawable to my android button.
But, background drawable is not working.

This is my drawable code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFEF1D1D" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and This is my layout code

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/booking"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6.5"
            android:text="bokking"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/booking_btn"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

Drawable is not applied to Button, but drawable is applied to AppCompatButton. I wonder why too.

When I applied this code, Only backgroundTint applies to buttons.

I spent a week on this issue, but I couldn't solve it.
plz help me

Comment: Are you using Material theme?

Comment: Yes I using Material theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply the background on the material button.

If you are using `Theme.MaterialComponents.*`, then the normal button also used as the material button forcefully.

You have two options.

1. change it to any AppCompat theme.
2. Still If you need a material theme for some components, then use any material theme with a bridge. like `Theme.MaterialComponents.*.Bridge`

So, If you will go with option 2, you can use material button as per your need.

use `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` for material button else use your normal button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Material Theme was the problem. I didn't know... thanks to you, I solved it well! Thank you.

Comment: Please note that you can also keep the Material theme, and use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` instead of `Button` or `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` if you want to customise your button !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem with the `Theme` since Android Studio 4.1, try changing the base `Theme` from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar`, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know it could be this simple… Thanks to you, I solved it!

Answer (score 1):

There is only one chance for that.I think you are using material theme.That's why the background property is not applying for button.If you want use that,change the theme to appcompat varaint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know Material Theme would be a problem. Thanks to you, I solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the `selector` in your XML. Use `Selector` instead of `Layer-List`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I solved the problem by applying Appcompat instead of Material Theme!